# Safe way to get alpha-numeric string from user input? (without preg_replace)

Tags: php, security

I have read many other questions regarding how to filter a string to "Alpha-numeric", but all of them suggest the `preg_replace()` method.

According to [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org):

> Function preg_replace() should not be used with unsanitised user
>   input, because the payload will be eval()’ed13.
>
> preg_replace("/.*/e","system(’echo /etc/passwd’)");
>
> Reflection also could
>   have code injection flaws. Refer to the appropriate reflection
>   documentations, since it is an advanced topic.

So now how do I achieve this without preg_replace?

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $_POST['data']);
// Notice the $_POST['data']
```

Comment: If the data is not valid, then why bother filtering it? Just reject it: `$result = ctype_alnum($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : null;`

Comment: `filter_input()` or `filter_var()`

Comment: @cmorrissey tried filter_ function, I tried it with many flags/filters , but the output was never same as above. e.g.: `filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH)`

Comment: @mistermartin Thank you, pardon me asking but are you sure ctype_alnum() can be trusted with user input?

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, I am sure.

Comment: the provided [case](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Code_Injection) is only valid if you use the [e-modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). which you shouldn't (and wouldn't) ever do, which is deprecated in php5.5 and removed in php7.0 - and which you simply do not need. if you use a typical regular expession without the implicit eval - you're perfectly safe. still, using php-provided validation functions is the better call anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no problem using `preg_replace()` to filter user inputs. The OWASP advice you've quoted is talking about the *pattern* not being user input itself.

However, I'd say that using filtered inputs is a problem by itself - you should validate instead. As in, don't accept invalid inputs.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me, I was shocked when I read that quote on OWASP, as I've used preg_place a lot of times.

Answer (score 2):

1. As others have pointed out, the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/) vulnerability you've linked only applies when you're evaluating the expression, which you shouldn't be doing anyway.
2. In my experience, regular expressions are highly frowned upon for such simple operations where PHP's built-in string functions suffice. The string functions are also faster.
3. If the data is not valid, then you shouldn't be filtering it, you should be rejecting it.

**Example:**

```
$result = ctype_alnum($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go for something like this:

```
<?php
$unsafe_input = 'some"""\'t&%^$@!`hing~~ unsafe \':[]435^%$^%*$^#'; // input from user

$safe_input = ''; // final sanitized string

// we want to allow 0-9 A-Z and a-z
// merge and flip so that we can use isset() later
$allowed_chars = array_flip(array_merge(range(0, 9), range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z')));

// loop each byte of the string
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($unsafe_input); ++$i)
{
    // isset() is lightyears faster than in_array()
    if(isset($allowed_chars[$unsafe_input[$i]]))
    {
        // good, sanitized, data
        $safe_input.= $unsafe_input[$i];
    }
}

echo $safe_input;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well we had similar situation and we use the following:

```
if ( ! preg_match('/^[a-z0-9:_\/|-]+$/i', $str))
{

//do your stuff
}
```